# show different form with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my HTML I have 4 fieldsets.
In the second fieldset there are 2 radio buttons. The first one needs to show the thirth fieldset and the second one needs to show the 4th fieldset.

Now the problem is that the second radio button does it's job. It shows the right fieldset and it hides when the first radio button is selected. But the first radio button does nothing anymore. 
It won't show the thirth fieldset. This is since I added the classList.remove for the fieldset2 var. 
I don't know why this line of code permanently hides the thirth fieldset.

**I just found out that the first var gets declined completely. Only the last var will be executed.
Even if I put them in different files or different functions and even if I make different classes for them in css the var will overwrite the first one...**

```
function form

   <form>
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Contactgegevens</legend>
     <label for="naam">Naam</label>
     <input type="text" id="naam" required/> 
     
     <label for="bedrijf">Naam bedrijf</label>
     <input type="email" id="bedrijf" required/>

     <label for="adres">Adres</label>
     <input type="text" id="adres" required/>
     
     <label for="postcode">Postcode</label>
     <input type="text" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}" id="postcode" placeholder="1234AB" required/>
     
     <label for="plaats">Plaatsnaam</label>
     <input type="number" id="plaats" required/>
     
     <label for="telefoon">Telefoon</label>
     <input type="tel" id="telefoon" />

     <label for="land">E-mail</label>
     <input type="text" id="land" placeholder="voorbeeld@email.com" required/>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Ik wil mij aanmelden voor:</legend>
     <label for="project">Een project</label>
     <input type="radio" name="aanmelden" id="project"/>
     
     <label for="stage">Een stage</label>
     <input type="radio" name="aanmelden" id="stage"/>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Project</legend>
     
     <label for="titel">Titel project</label>
     <input type="text" id="titel" />
     
     <label for="omschrijving">Opdrachtomschrijving</label>
     <textarea id="omschrijving" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
     
     <label for="doelgroep">Doelgroepomschrijving</label>
     <textarea id="doelgroep" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
     
     <label for="intentie">Intentie van het project</label>
     <textarea id="intentie" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>
     
     <label for="looptijd">Looptijd</label>
     <input type="text" id="looptijd" placeholder="Bijv: 10 weken"/>
     
     <label for="deadline">Deadline</label>
     <input type="text" id="deadline" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj"/>
     
     <label for="geschikt">Geschikt voor</label>
     <select id="geschikt">
      <option>Eerstejaar studenten</option>
      <option>Tweedejaars studenten</option>
      <option>Derdejaars studenten</option>
      <option>Afstudeer studenten</option>
      <option>Onbekend</option>
     </select>
    </fieldset>
    
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Stage</legend>
     
     <label for="geschikt2">Geschikt voor</label>
     <select id="geschikt2">
      <option>Tweedejaars studenten</option>
      <option>Afstudeer studenten</option>
      <option>Onbekend</option>
     </select>
     
     <label for="hoelang">Hoelang is de stage?</label>
     <select id="hoelang">
      <option>10 weken</option>
      <option>20 weken</option>
     </select>
     
     <label for="begindatum">Begindatum</label>
     <input type="text" id="begindatum" placeholder="dd-mm-jjjj"/>

     <label for="werkzaamheden">Omschrijving stagewerkzaamheden</label>
     <textarea id="werkzaamheden" rows="6" cols="25"></textarea>    
    </fieldset>
   </form>


Keuze(){
    

console.log("hoi")
 
     var fieldset = document.querySelector('fieldset:nth-of-type(3)');
 
     fieldset.classList.add('hidefield');
 
 document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:first-of-type').onclick = function() {
  fieldset.classList.add('showfield');
 }
 
 document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:last-of-type').onclick = function() {
  fieldset.classList.remove('showfield');
 }
 
 var fieldset2 = document.querySelector('fieldset:nth-of-type(4)');
 
 fieldset2.classList.add('hidefield');
 
 document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:last-of-type').onclick = function() {
  fieldset2.classList.add('showfield');
 }
 
     document.querySelector('input[type="radio"]:first-of-type').onclick = function() {
      fieldset2.classList.remove('showfield');
     }
    }
    window.onload=formKeuze;
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @Jos, kindly post your code in code snippet, edit your post and press `Ctrl + M`

Comment: @Arvind sorry didn't know it worked that way. thanks for the tip :)